# How to pass docker run argument to docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ros

Say I want to run the following:

```
   docker run -it \
        --env="DISPLAY" \
        --env="QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1" \
        --volume="/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw" \
        my_image
```

The above runs fine and I am able to get the Gui I want. However, if I want to run the above using a `docker-compose` file, how would I do that? I tried:

```
version: '3'
services:
  service-1:
    build: ./dockerfiles
    environment:
      - DISPLAY
      - QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1
    volumes:
      - ~/.ssh:/root/.ssh
      - ./dockerfiles:/usr/src/app
      - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw
```

But it did not work, whenever I tried:

```
Docker run -it my_image
```

I got the following error whenever I want to pull up a GUI (like Rviz from ROS):

```
QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
```

Comment: So the docker run command works fine directly?

Comment: Yes it works, I just want to simplify the process by adding all the docker run arguments into docker-compose. Still trying to figure it out.

Comment: Try `docker-compose up` and this should build the container based on your docker-compose.yml specification.

Comment: `docker run -it my_image` will not work because you are not passing any of the environment variables as such. What you need to do is as @tedsmitt said, use `docker-compose up` which will then use the environment variables and run the container with those variables set

Comment: did you tried `docker-compose up -d --build`?